# Removing movieclips from the stage

Tags: flash, actionscript, stage

I am working on a side-scrolling game in Flash Actionscript 3.0.  Right now I am trying to allow the Player to advance to the next level by touching a certain object.  Before the next level is loaded, I try to remove all of the previous level's assets (background and "floor"), which are MovieClips, from the stage.  When the next level loads, I can still see the previous level's assets, although the Player cannot interact with them.

I have looked around the Internet and tried a few methods to fix my problem, but I have gotten nowhere.  Following is the code I use to transition from one level to the next.  the 'bgContainer' contains only the unloaded level's background MovieClip and the 'allContainer' contains the unloaded level's floor and other environmental objects.  These containers are later loaded with the objects required in the next level.

```
// Check if the Player has touched Level 1's end point
    private function checkLevel1To2Collision(event:Event):void {
        // Has the Player touched Level 1's end point?
        if (HitTest.intersects(player, level1To2, this)) {

                // Remove Level 1's Background from the stage
                //stage.removeChild(bgContainer);

                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollScreen);

                // Clear everything from the stage (only if there is already something on the stage)
                //while (numChildren > 0) {

                    //for (var stgIndex = 0; stgIndex < stage.numChildren; stgIndex++) {
                        //stage.removeChildAt(0);
                    //}
                //}
                //}

                stage.removeChild(allContainer);
                stage.removeChild(bgContainer);

                // Clear out all elements from the 'allContainer' before reloading the current level
                for (var allIndex1:int = 0; allIndex1 < allContainer.numChildren; allIndex1++) {
                    allContainer.removeChildAt(allIndex1);
                    //if (stage.getChildAt(allIndex1)) {
                        //stage.removeChildAt(allIndex1);
                    //}
                }

                // Remove the elements within 'bgContainer' from the stage
                for (var bgIndex1:int = 0; bgIndex1 < bgContainer.numChildren; bgIndex1++) {
                    bgContainer.removeChildAt(bgIndex1);
                    //if (stage.getChildAt(bgIndex1)) {
                        //stage.removeChildAt(bgIndex1);
                    //}
                }


                // Load Level 2
                loadLevel2(event);
        }
    } // End of 'checkLevel1To2Collision' function
```

As can be seen, I have tried at least two techniques to the unload the previous level's assets.  I have tried going through the stage and removing all elements one by one using a 'for' loop.  And I have tried removing the stage element at index 0 while the stage has an object on it. I also tried referring to 'root' instead of 'stage' while adding objects using 'addChildAt().'  None of those techniques worked.  I still have no idea why the previous level will not be unloaded.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this.removeChild, rather than stage.removeChild?

Comment: Could you maybe post the code where you add the elements to the stage and your containers?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I tried using "this.removeChild" instead of "stage.removeChild." But that causes an error saying that "this" is not a child of a Display Object.  I just tried it again but it did not do anything.

Comment: You don't provide code for when you add the children, so I was guessing that maybe you added the children to "this", rather than the stage.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: I add children to the Containers (which are MovieClips) using the "addChild()" function. So if I add something to the "envContainer," I use this: "envContainer.addChild(object)." When my objects have been added to their respective Containers, I add the Containers to the stage, using "stage.addChild(container)."

Comment: It seems to me that if the children of the containers are added properly, then just removing the containers from the stage should handle the visibility issues.  If it's not, you have something else going on in your code, but since you haven't provided that code there is no way to pinpoint it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure what the parent of allContainer is, then use

```
allContainer.parent && allContainer.parent.removeChild(allContainer.parent);
```

(this left-side just acts as a guard to ensure that the right-side is called only if allContainer is on the stage, you could alternatively write it as:)

```
if (allContainer.parent)
{
    allContainer.parent.removeChild(allContainer.parent);
}
```

The for-loop you write is also problematic, because after you've deleted the first child at 0, the children all shift down one index, so the child at 1 is now at 0 but your index has moved to 1, so you keep missing children! Instead use this:

```
while (allContainer.numChildren)
{
    allContainer.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

This way the while loop will keep looping around until all the children of allContainer are removed.

Alternatively, if you want this to run optimally quickly, use

```
var i:int = allContainer.numChildren;
while (i--)
{
    allContainer.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The 'while' loop clears the containers okay, I thinky. It doesn't clear the stage.  At "while (stage.numChildren)," the compiler complains about a reference to a "null" object. I must figure what object is considered "null."

When the program loads, I add "eventListeners" to the stage. These eventListeners control player movement and other things. I'm suspecting that when I try to clear the stage, these listeners are removed, causing issues.

To fix this I tried adding Listeners to 'this,' but that didn't work. Can I add these Listeners to anything other than the stage?

Comment: I wouldn't run it over stage, there are some cases where the flash player may add other things to the stage (like if you go fullscreen, the little warning for example). My advice - just add one Sprite to stage, call it "root" or something, then add everything to that. Don't add anything else to stage, add everything else to root. That way you can be sure that the only things on the stage are what you've added.

Comment: Thinking about it further - I bet you're running the removal script from within a Sprite that's added to the stage. You can't do that because as soon as that child is removed from the stage, it will lose reference to the stage (so it's reporting that 'stage' is null, not any member of stage).

Comment: So it sounds like you've got some scope problems going on. Not sure how to help you much more than this...

Comment: Okay, I can try adding the 'root' sprite to the stage. What about my eventListeners, though? Should those be added to the 'root' sprite, too? As I said before, they only seemed to work when added to the stage.

Comment: As for removing elements from the stage, I tried using a while loop that checks if the stage has children (while(stage.numChildren)).  Then the loop removes the stage child at 0. I don't reference any sprite within this loop; I reference only the stage and the element at index 0. I am thinking that I might have to skip over the eventListeners while running this loop, so that they don't cause a "null" error. I shall investigate further.

Comment: Okay, I think I have finally cracked it. I added my containers to the 'this,' not 'stage.' When I want to clear the screen, I remove all elements from the 'this' in a while loop.  I still add my EventListeners (KeyPressed, KeyReleased, etc.) to the stage. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: No problem - mark issue as the answer if you think I answered it!