# Flash CS6: How to embed a .swf file into another .swf file which will open when user clicks button

Tags: flash, embed

I am total newbie to Flash.  I have no clue how to make my buttons on my menu page in Flash clickable and attached to another swf file of mine.  I want the user to click on the button and my other flash movie will appear and begin to play.  I need like total newbie directions for this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a little late.. But im a total noob to Action script 2.. i'm okay at Action script 3 though.. The only thing i can really Suggest is maybe using the 
    `loadMovieNum("NameOrLinkToSwf.swf",0,"GET");` method of loading an Swf.. Possibly look into onClickListeners.. I Have not Gotten that far into AS2 yet but it shouldn't be too hard.. Goodluck to whoever Reads this

Answer (score -1):

Hrm, someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the only way to do this to write some code for the button(s) you have and have it load the external swf(s) then place it on stage.

I suggest looking up creating buttons in actionscript 2 or 3 and using the MovieClip. loadMovie() method in actionscript 2 or Loader class in actionscript 3, which ever language you want to use (though, I suggest using AS3).

There is actually another question asking this:
[Loading another swf file using AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642154/loading-another-swf-file-using-as3)